# Can I see a simple example of ogg audio decoding

Tags: c++, http, signal-processing, ogg, icecast

I want to write my own icecast2 client because I can't seem to find one that will work with what I need. But, I am so overwhelmed by everything that entails. I'm familiar with networking, and I know a thing or too about audio as well. But, I've never written or used a decoder. I see a lot of things on xiph.org that could be useful if I could just see the basics.

Could someone post an answer that contains a few frames of ogg with an example of how to convert that raw ogg into audio (does it ultimately turn into wav to play?)

Comment: posting the complete code to parse ogg? nope sorry. That is quite a development effort... libraries on the other hand: http://www.libsdl.org/ -> ( http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL_mixer:Tutorials:Playing_an_OGG_Music_File )

Comment: What codec are you planning to use?  Ogg is just the container.  Vorbis?

Comment: Hi @Brad I am trying to choose between libogg and libvorbis. How can I get to know what the difference is? I see that once icecast I connected to is sending libvorbis.

Comment: I now see how to at least get the vorbis library to build. I had to download ogg, build it, and then reference the framework in vorbis. @Najzero I do find this libsdl library interesting. I'll look into its capabilities, but at first glance it seems to only decode files not streams.

Comment: @Gandalf458 Vorbis is the actual codec.  Ogg is just a container than could contain all sorts of codec.  Vorbis and FLAC are the most common codecs used within an Ogg wrapper, but you could use just about anything you want.